# double keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript

i was looking at [W3schools javascript keywords](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp), am wondering what the "double" keyword is used for. Can't find any documentation on it

Comment: It's not used (yet), but this is reserved word for potential future something.

Comment: @dfsq— *double* isn't a reserved word. It was in ECMA-262 ed 3, but isn't in either ES5 (which superseded ed 3) or ECMAScript 2015 (the current standard).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing. It was just reserved as it was thought likely to be used in future versions of the language.

It hasn't been reserved since ECMAScript 3.